# Leveling cantrips as a multiclass?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, cantrips

Let's say I have a character who has Booming Blade and is a level 3 Sorcerer, and level 2 Fighter, would that still count as having levelled Booming Blade? Or do I need the Sorcerer class to reach level 5?